# Heroku Deployment error H10 "configuration /app/config.ru not found"

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment, sinatra

I'm deploying my Sinatra application to Heroku and when I got to `heroku logs` I'm seeing the following trace:

```
State changed from crashed to starting
configuration /app/config.ru not found
State changed from starting to crashed
 at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=... request_id=... status=503 bytes=
...heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=... dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 31614`
Process exited with status 1
```

What's wrong - is it my ruby version (`ruby 1.9.3p484`)...I really don't know what it could be. Everything works great in localhost.

Comment: Does the command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 31614` work locally?

Comment: @hjing `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 31614` does not work locally. Instead I get the message `configuration /home/.../config.ru not found`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, got the answer with the pointer about `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 31614` not working locally. What was wrong was that I had not added a `config.ru` file. Following the guide at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack  I simple did `touch config.ru`, then added the lines:

```
require './server.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

to my `config.ru`file.

Then I got a message that the application did not know what pry was: `/app/server.rb:2:in 'require': cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)`, so I removed `require 'pry'` from server.rb, pushed to github:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

and finally pushed it to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```